# Why pandas.Series.values drops some scalar data exists in original Series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.Series` object `docs` of which scalar values are string.

when I tries to iterate over `docs.values`, for example make `list(docs)`, some of the scalar entries are dropped, or become a `NoneType`.

For instance, given `target_index` is an index with buggy issue, when I check `docs[target_index]`, it returns a string data. However, when I execute `list(docs)[target_index]`, it returns None.

Since `pandas.Series.values` turn data into `numpy.ndarray`, I guess the issue has something to do with numpy data type or something, but I cannot figure out whats going wrong exactly.

Here is the buggy json file of dataframe

https://gist.github.com/goodcheer/f9c990171a57ff053b4b0539396f63f6

`docs` is the `profile` column series

Comment: I can t reproduce it here. Can you give a more concrete example? Or an example of a buggy index ?

Comment: Couldn't find an example where this happened. But notice that `list(docs)[target_index]` returns the value in position `target_index`, whereas `docs[target_index]` returns the value in *index* `target_index`. For example, the third element of your series has index `10`. If you do `docs[10]`, you'll get the third value, but if you do `list(docs)[10]` you'll get the tenth value.

Comment: @RafaelC yeah you were right. I have confused with value position and index. Thankyou !